# Difference between upvar 0 and upvar 1 in TCL

Tags: tcl, upvar

Can anyone let me know the difference between `upvar 0` and `upvar 1` in TCL, how we can use in real time. Kindly, if someone explain with example, it makes me more clear.

Answer (score 10):

When you are calling a bunch of procedures, you get a *stack* of stack frames. It's in the name. We might visualise this like so:

```
abc 123 456
   bcd 321 456
      cde 654 321
```

OK, so we've got `abc` calling `bcd` calling `cde`. Simple.

The `0` and `1` in `upvar` say how many levels to go up the stack when looking up the variable to link to. `1` means go up one level (i.e., to the *caller* of the current frame), say from `cde` to `bcd` in our example, `2` would go from `cde` up to `abc` and `3` all the way up to the global evaluation level where overall scripts and callbacks run. `0` is a special case of this; it means do the lookup in the *current* stack frame. There's also the ability to use indexing from the base of the stack by putting `#` in front of the name, so `#0` indicates the global frame, `#1` the first thing it calls.

The most common use of `upvar` is `upvar 1` (and if you leave the level out, that's what it does). `upvar 0` is only really used when you want to get a different (usually easier to work with) name for a variable. The next most common one is `upvar #0`, though `global` is a much more common shorthand there (which matches the unqualified parts of the name for your convenience). Other forms are rare; for example, `upvar 2` is usually an indication of really confusing and tangled code, and hardly anyone ever used `upvar #1` before Tcl 8.6's coroutines. I've never seen `upvar 3` or `upvar #2` in the wild (though *computed* level indicators are present in some object systems for Tcl).

### Example of `upvar 1` — pass variable by name:

```
proc mult-by {varName multiplier} {
    upvar 1 $varName var
    set var [expr {$var * $multiplier}]
}

set x 2
mult-by x 13
puts "x is now $x"
# x is now 26
```

### Example of `upvar 0` — simplify variable name:

```
proc remember {name contents} {
    global my_memory_array
    upvar 0 my_memory_array($name) var
    if {[info exist var]} {
        set var "\"$var $contents\""
    } else {
        set var "\"$name $contents\""
    }
}

remember x 123
remember y 234
remember x 345
remember y 456
parray my_memory_array
# my_memory_array(x) = ""x 123" 345"
# my_memory_array(y) = ""y 234" 456"
```

Comment: Thanks alot donal i understood **upvar** 1 and **upvar #0** very clearly and upvar 0 i understood your example, but i cant understand **the real time use of upvar 0.** According to my understanding it seems creating a variable name var on remember proc scope. If you make me more clear that would be fine. I am eagerly waiting for your comments

Answer (score 2):

unlike upvar 1 , upvar 0 creates alias for the variable.
for ex:

```
    set a 4 
proc upvar1 {a} {
upvar 1 a b
incr a 4
incr b 3
puts "output is $a $b"
}
proc upvar0 {a} {
upvar 0 a b
incr a 4
incr b 3
puts "output is $a $b"
}
upvar1 $a
puts "in global frame value of a is  $a"

set a 4
upvar0 $a
puts "in global frame value of a is  $a"
```

Output:

```
output is 8 7
in global frame value of a is  7
output is 11 11
in global frame value of a is  4
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think an example will make the difference quite clear:

Lets say we have a function test_upvar1:

```
proc test_upvar1 {} {
    upvar 1 a b
    incr b
}
```

And a function test_upvar0:

```
proc test_upvar0 {} {
    upvar 0 a b
    incr b
}
```

Now we set variable a and call both function to see what happens:

```
set a 5
test_upvar1
```

This will return 6

```
set a 5
test_upvar0
```

Will return 1

This happens because we select with zero and one our execution frame 0 links in the same execution frame 1 a frame higher.

See http://wiki.tcl.tk/1508